# many to many relation in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, has-many-through, has-many

I take a look at these 2 blog posts and feel a little obscure about has_many relationship in RoR:

In this one: http://kconrails.com/2010/01/16/many-to-many-relationships-in-ruby-on-rails/ , in "has_many :through" section, the author said the migration files for join table **Contributions** is like:

```
class CreateContributions &lt; ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :contributions do |t|
      t.references :artist
      t.references :song
      t.string :instrument
      t.timestamps
    end
...........
```

So the migration of join table will reference to 2 table **Artist** and **Song** using **t.references :artist** and **t.references :song**. And if we want to access an attribute like the instrument artist play for that song, we can access it using join table **Contributions**.

In the second post: http://kconrails.com/2010/01/29/has_and_belongs_to_many-associations-in-ruby-on-rails/. Section: "has_many :through", author introduce "full-fledged table" named **Categorizations**. The migration is like below:

```
class CreateCategorizations < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :categorizations do |t|
      t.integer :category_id
      t.integer :item_id
      t.timestamps
    end
...........
```

So the migration of **full-fledged table** will reference to 2 table Category and Item by **t.integer :category_id** and **t.integer :item_id**. And we can only access the attributes specific to something that both related to 2 attributes of this table like the timestamps, can we add more attributes (something like **t.string :instrument**) to the model as above?

For example, If i have many-to-many relation models like **Manufacturer** and **Product**, I want to keep track of the **Price**, I should put it into full-fledged table, right? But if I want to just add one attribute but do not keep track of it like **Original_From** (show where the product was produced), I only need to put into join table?

Can I generalize it this way: when the number of attributes are limited and do not important to keep track, use the join table. When the number of attributes are many and we want to keep track, we will use full-fledged table. Is it correct?

What are the differences when we access the data? Like if i want to access the Price or the Location in the example above?

I still not clear about the different between full-fledged table and join table. Please give me some ideas. Thank you very much!

Comment: They are technically the same.  In some cases you want to tag each record in the join table with an attribute that indicates if this combination of FKs are, for example, active  or those two use an instrument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have this mostly right.  `has_and_belongs_to_many` (HABTM) on both models of a many-to-many relationship assumes a simple join table between (no id, no timestamps, just foreign keys to each of the tables' primary keys.)

If the relationship itself (the join table) is "useful" -- something you would want to reference in your class, in particular because it has a field of its own, you would define it as its own model and use `has_many :through =>` to define the relationship on both sides, with `belongs_to` in the new model.  This is the "full fledged" option.

Mostly, you'll get the same methods with either option (e.g. you'll get a `locations` method on Price, and a `prices` method on Location).  But certainly the HABTM option is more limited.

For example, I found recently that the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` method doesn't work with simple HABTM, but works fine with `has_many :through`.

I think this  [Rails guide does a really good job of describing when to use one versus the other](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has_many-through-and-has_and_belongs_to_many).

(And it looks like the coming Rails 4.0 has much better support for HABTM and a few new features for dealing with one-to-many and many-to-many relationships :-)

Comment: Yeah, I understand the different between HABTM and has_many, my only concern is about join table and full-fledged table. But D3mon-1stVFW said that it is technically the same.

Comment: So how can I access the data from other table? Like if i have table Product(name), Manufacturer(name), Manufacturing(product_id, manufacturer_id, price), how can I get the name of the product through join/full-fledged table ?
I can only get the product_id or manufacturer_id through product.manufacturing.manufacturer_id or manufacturer.manufacturing.product_id. I don't know how to reverse the name of the manufacturer or product from these relation.

Comment: The tables can be technically the same, but the way Rails understands the relationships is what is subtly different.

Comment: Answering second comment question: I think Product/Manufacturer is not a good example; a product has one manufacturer, right, so this isn't really a many-to-many relationship.  Maybe Product/Store is what you are thinking -- a product can be sold by many stores, and a store sells many products.  The middle table is important because it might track price, which is different for every store-product combination.  So you set up 2 'has_many` relationships on the outside tables -- one that gets you *through* the middle table, the other that gets you *to* the middle table.

Comment: So what I misunderstand is the join table is for HABTM and "full fledged" option is for has_many/belongs_to model. Ok I got it. Can you tell me how can I, from one table, access the attribute on the other table through join model? That is what i'm not understand right now.

Comment: I have to run.  Work on this more on your own -- you're close!